# Create new line then copy and paste row

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create an excel macro to select a range of cells then insert new row every other row then copy and paste each row.

For example.

|  |
| --- |
| apples |
| oranges |
| mangos |

My desired goal is

|  |
| --- |
| apples |
| apples |
| oranges |
| oranges |
| mangos |
| mangos |

I have thousands of rows and a macro would be nice.

This Inserts a new row,every other row.

```
Sub InsertNewRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CountRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Set rng = Selection
    CountRow = rng.EntireRow.Count
    
    For i = 1 To CountRow
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

How can I duplicate the lines in the range too?

Comment: Just wondering, Is it critical inserting new rows? I mean, wouldn't work a code that copies twice keeping same order?. So If range A2:A4 = Apples / Oranges / Mangos, the code would copy twice and would Be A2:A7 =  Apples / Apples / Oranges / Oranges / Mangos / Mangos. Copying is faster than inserting new rows if you have thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not inserting rows, this code copies and pastes each value twice. Inserting rows is really time consuming.

Here's a screenshot of before/after running code:

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim MyData As Variant
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Initial_Row As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non blank cell in column A

MyData = Range("A1:A" & LR).Value 'all data into array

Initial_Row = 1 'initial row where data starts pasting

For i = 1 To UBound(MyData) Step 1
    Range("A" & Initial_Row & ":A" & Initial_Row + 1).Value = MyData(i, 1)
    Initial_Row = Initial_Row + 2
Next i

Erase MyData 'delete data
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read the values into an array and duplicate them into another array and finally write that array to the cells. This is much faster than duplicating cells.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DuplicateSelectedRows()
    Dim SelRng As Range
    Set SelRng = Selection
    
    ' read values into array
    Dim SelectedValues As Variant
    SelectedValues = SelRng.Value
    
    ' create output array of double the size
    Dim DuplicatedValues As Variant
    ReDim DuplicatedValues(1 To UBound(SelectedValues, 1) * 2, 1 To UBound(SelectedValues, 2))
    
    ' duplicate values
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(SelectedValues, 1)
        DuplicatedValues(iRow * 2 - 1, 1) = SelectedValues(iRow, 1)
        DuplicatedValues(iRow * 2, 1) = SelectedValues(iRow, 1)
    Next iRow
    
    ' output values
    SelRng.Cells(1, 1).Resize(RowSize:=UBound(DuplicatedValues)).Value = DuplicatedValues
End Sub
```